# How to delete multiple documents in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a java program that finds documents based on certain date condition and removes all of them. I am not sure how to remove those documents once found. When I query the MongoDB database using following command it shows me `2706` documents present.

**MongoDB version: 3.0**

**Mongo-Java driver version: 3.1.0**

**Mongo Shell command:**

```
db.jobs.find({"startTime" : { $gte : "2015-11-04 00:00:00"}}).count();
Output: 2706
```

I have the following java program that does more or less similar to the above command.

**Java code:**

```
MongoDatabase database = DataSourceFactory.getDatabase(DatabaseType.MONGODB.name());
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("jobs");
//find and delete existing documents first
String currentDate = GenericUtils.getCurrentDate() + " 00:00:00";
Document doc = collection.findOneAndDelete(gte("startTime", currentDate));
```

I am not sure if usage of `findOneAndDelete()` method is the way to go.  Do I have to write a loop that does this? Is there a way to find and remove all the records in a single shot?

Not sure how to remove all the records and get a count of how many got deleted.

I googled and found some online tutorials but most of them are based on older versions `2.1, 2.2` etc.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

The `deleteMany()` method can be used for finding and deleting documents in a single shot.

```
DeleteResult deleteResult = collection.deleteMany(gte("startTime", currentDate));
LOG.debug(deleteResult.getDeletedCount() + " document(s) deleted.....");
```